# Captcha image is not detected but installed and working properly

Tags: 7, installation

I have installed [Captcha](https://www.drupal.org/project/captcha) and Image Captcha submodule (included in Captcha). It works perfectly, and displays the captcha image. However, when trying to install Captcha Refresh module, I found that Drupal believes that the module is not installed. I had to reinstall once ago, many time ago, the module Captcha because it was not working (uninstalled, deleted, uploaded again, installed). Maybe this corrupted the system table or anything? How can I teach Drupal to detect the module?

Answer (score 0):

I have found this [reference](https://www.drupal.org/node/799884) and following the comments, I detected that I had replicated the folder /modules/ inside of /sites/all/modules/, and the first folder contained a replica of the captcha folder, so this is why Drupal was confused about what module was installed. After deleting the folder, everything went OK.

What convinced me is that I had a copy of the whole database and a mirror site, but obviously without the replicated folder, and in the mirror site everything went OK. After discarding a permissions problem, I was convinced that it was a duplicate folder, and had to look in all places. Finally, it was at glance.