# Why can't I uninstall a module if I deleted a field type in a content type?

Tags: entities, installation

I have an installation of Drupal 7. I installed Field Collection module. I created a content type (Books), added a collection type field, and created a View showing these data. Now, I deleted the collection type field in Books, and now I am not able to uninstall the module. I have run cron and cache delete to no avail. The message displayed in the modules page is the following.

Field collection

> 7.x-1.0-beta11+13-dev
>   Provides a field collection field, to which any number of fields can be attached.
>   Requires: Entity API (enabled)
>   Required by: Drupal (**Fields pending deletion**)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From http://www.drupalwoo.com/content/blog/cant-disable-module-drupal-fields-pending-deletion :

> All of us who have been working with Drupal for a while have run into
>   this issue: you want to disable a module that you are no longer using,
>   but it's grayed-out on the 'Modules' tab, and so you aren't able to
>   disable and uninstall it.
>
> It says Required by: Drupal (Fields pending deletion)
>
> Required by: Drupal (Fields pending deletion)
>
> Well, you know what this means, so you go to the fields list screen at
>   /admin/reports/fields
>
> You delete all the fields that were related to this module, you run
>   cron multiple times (that's what all the replies to this problem say),
>   and still, you cannot disable the module.
>
> If this is happening to you, as it happened to me recently with the
>   Geofield module, here's the quick fix:
>
> Go into the field_config table in your Drupal database, and look for
>   the field in question.  It should say that the field in question has
>   been deleted already:

Try running this query in your database.

```
    DELETE FROM `field_config` WHERE `field_config`.`deleted` = 1;
```

Then, clear the cache.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I cannot believe this or the other solution (essentially the same) are not automatic. I was adviced to never ever, under any circumstance, to delete directly from the database.

Comment: @Cesar another solution is  Clear cache several Times :)
I answer before him :D

Answer (score 2):

You can try this process

Log into database and ->

```
Select * from field_config where type = "field_collection"
```

Delete the rows

Same with field config instance table like

```
SELECT * FROM field_config_instance where entity_type = "field_collection";
```

Delete the rows

You can also check.

> 1.) first remove all the fields inside the Fields Collection.
>
> 2.) Then remove the field collection from the content type
>
> 3.) Run the Cron
>
> 4.) try to disable the module, if you cannot then Go ahead with first query statements above.

Get more details [Here](https://www.drupal.org/node/1867134).

Comment: It worked without running cron. Shouldn't this procedure be automatic?

Comment: No i think for field collection this not automatic. But i am not sure. You need to do more RND on it. Thank you :)

Comment: Well, after finding a extremely rare bug in Drupal I am used to deleting in core tables. It was a module not showing up. Still problems after uninstalling, installing again, deleting from MySQL tables. Finally, I had discovered that I had uploaded manually the folder of the module to  modules and there were two copies, one in modules and the other one in sites/all/modules. It is incredible that Drupal does not throw an exception in that case. http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/180103/captcha-image-is-not-detected-but-installed-and-working-properly

Comment: What I have done - if `field_catfood` shows error, then find `catfood` in the MySQL, `config` table, and delete the keys- with `field_catfood` name